# Shutdown process stuck at systemd-shutdown: waiting for process: systemd-journal

Tags: shutdown, systemd, crash

After power off/shutdown, the process is stuck here. What am I supposed to do now? This is taking forever. Should I kill the power?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You should find out why systemd-journal is taking too much time. Version, `lsb_release -r`? Disk space `df -h -x squashfs -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs`? Up-to-date? Check `journalctl` options like `--flush` `--rotate`.